# Can I get a javascript file reference to act the same as an HTML file input?

Tags: javascript, html, input, getelementbyid

I'm using a javascript plugin that works in conjunction with a standard HTML input tag. So the tag looks like:

```
<input id='input' type='file' />
```

And my javascript looks like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');                
input.onchange = function(e) {
    getOrientation(input.files[0], function(orientation) {
        //  do some stuff
    });
}
```

The getOrientation function returns information about the file that I need.

My problem is that I don't use the HTML input tag in my application. I'd like to feed this function a reference to a file that's the href attribute of an anchor tag, like this:

```
var myFile = $("#AnchorTagName").attr("href");
```

Or I could use an img attribute 'src' instead, and just hide the image.

Can anyone tell me if I can replace the contents of an HTML input tag with some javascript reference to a file?

Comment: you can't get a clients files yourself. they have to action to give you access to specific files (i.e. the file input). So assuming the file you want is on their machine, this isn't possible. Otherwise, you may want to be more specific where this file location is going to point to

Comment: My files are on the server side, and I update the anchor tag 'href' attribute with jquery.

Comment: in that case, you can send the file stream to the client and read it with [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: The Input tag grabs a copy of the file and places it server-side. My files are already on the server. I just need a way to reference them that can be made to work the same way that the input tag does.

Comment: yes, so you need it in File or Blob format, then you can convert between those or just use the one that the plugin requires (likely both are valid)